# Confused about file locations of ruby gems

Tags: ruby

I am using ubuntu 10+, when I do this:
$locate rubygems.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.10/lib/rubygems.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb

why there are two rubygems.rb here, which is used by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rubygems-update is a gem for upgrading rubygems from an old version. [See here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page14). The latter is used by default (i.e. /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb)